# CouchDB _change Feed

Tags: couchdb

for my application I implemented a logical seperation of my documents with a type attribute. I have several views. I implemented for every view a dedicated change feed which gets triggerd if a certain document was added or updated. At the moment the performance is quite well, do I have to expect a slow down in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, every filter function associated with your feed is executed once for each new (or updated) document. So, you may expect a slowdown with a large number of concurrent inserts and updates. It's not something related to the database dimension, but to the number of concurrent updates.

Comment: Thx for you input. So a slowdown is possible. The good news is, that i expect only a few bulk inserts over a longer period. After that only a few documents will be updated by a client software. The reason behind all these filtered feed changes is to build/update all assigned views to a document.